# Why is casting from List<A> to List<B> not recommended?

Tags: java, list, casting

I [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-in-java) that if I have two classes:

```
public class A {}
public class B extends A {}
```

I can cast from a `List<A>` to `List<B>` by doing this:

```
List<B> list = (List<B>)(List<?>) collectionOfListA;
```

This would generate a warning, but it works. However, I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917844/how-to-cast-listobject-to-listmyclass) that this is not recommended. Is it true in that case?

If I know it's returning me a `List<B>`, why making this cast is such a bad practice?

Please note that I want to know why, in this case, this is a bad practice, not why there is a warning. And "it's a bad practice because it generates a warning" is not a good answer.

Comment: What if class `B` have methods that class `A` doesn't? Via listB you should be able to safely invoke something like `listB.get(0).methodFromB()`, but since `listB` was originally `listA` there is chance that beside objects B it will also contains objects A which cant invoke `methodFromB()`.

Comment: If I'm casting it's because I know there aren't any A there... I mean: `Object a = "string"; Integer b = (Integer)a;` The compiler won't complain about this...

Comment: OK, but it is your knowledge (assumption). Compiler can't know about it, that is why it gives you warning. Since later no one can stop you from putting A object in `listA` it can be dangerous for listB. That is why it is not recommended to cast from `List<A>` to `List<B>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting the list directly is bad because it subverts the Java type system. The cast will always succeed, but the program may fail later with a `ClassCastException` when you go to retrieve items, at which point the source of the error may be unclear.

In general you want your program to fail as close to the source of the error as possible. If you cast the list, it may be passed around for a while before someone actually tries to access elements and by the time it throws a `ClassCastException` it might be really hard to track it back to that cast (at the very least hard-*er* than if the program failed at the cast).

From your comments it seems like you're sure that everything in `listA` is actually a `B` in which case I would recommend:

```
List<B> listB = new ArrayList(listA.size());
for (A a : listA) {
  if (a == null || a instanceof B) {
    listB.add((B) a);
  } else {
    //Either ignore or throw exception
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

An apple **is a** fruit, but a list of apples **is-not** a list of fruit.

If it was, you could put a banana in a list of apples

Comment: I'm casting a list of fruits to a list of apples because I know there are only apples there. Why is it a bad practice?

Comment: @Roberto Then why not just have a list of apples to begin with?

Comment: No control over the source that returns me a list of fruits; I wanted to create an Apple class with methods to ease the handling of those fruits.

Answer (score 2):

For this to make sense, you have to understand that `List<A>` and `List<B>` are two different types, not hierarchically related, *even if `A` and `B` are hierarchically related*. Even if `B` was a subclass of `A`, casting a `List<B>` to a `List<A>` is bad because it could allow you to add to that list instances of `A` (but not `B`) and the compiler would happily do that, even though it wouldn't agree with the actual (runtime) type of the collection.

I didn't know that you can circumvent this in Java, but if you can it's only because of *type erasure*: because Java creates one class such as `List<Object>` and, for different "implementations" of that generic class, it merely adds casts in your code before compiling it. This is contrast to (say) C#, which actually uses the `List<T>` only as a "compiled" template (called "generic definition"), to create the concrete types on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Generics work bit differently, so **list< B >** is not of type **list< A >** though **B** is a type of **A**.