# What is the best way to convert List<MyObject> to List<IMyInterface>?

Tags: c#, collections, interface

I have a list of objects.  Lets call them MyObject and i need to convert them to a list of IMyInterface as i want to add other things to the list that are not MyObject but also implement my interface.  I tried this but it doesn't work . .

```
 List<IMyInterface> myList = myObjectList;  //myObjectList is a List<MyObject>
```

any suggestions?  do i need to cast each item in the array upfront?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
List<IMyInterface> l = myList.OfType<IMyInterface>().ToList();
```

Comment: You will need `.ToList()` on the end of that :)

Comment: Semantically speaking, it would be more correct to use `Cast<T>()`.

Comment: Does the fact that this actually makes a new list cause an issue for the op?

Answer (score 3):

```
myList.Cast<IMyInterface>().ToList()
```

`OfType<>` also works, but is intended as a filter instead of a conversion of every item.

Answer (score 0):

Converting n list to an interface list is very easy  all you got to do is to add to the end of `myobjectlist` this code pieace `.OfType<IMyInterface>().ToList() , 
and you can use`mylistobject.Cast` as well

Here are some usefull links

Link1
[How do you cast a List of supertypes to a List of subtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-in-java)
Link2
[How to cast List<Object> to List<MyClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917844/how-to-cast-listobject-to-listmyclass)
Link3

Full code for OffType conversion

```
List<IMyInteface>1 = mylistobject.OfType(IMyInterface>().ToList() ;
```

Full code for Cast conversion

```
 List<IMyInteface>1 = mylistobject.Cast(IMyInterface>().ToList() ;
```

And You can try the following code as well

```
var targetList = origList
  .Select(x => new TargetType() { SomeValue = x.SomeValue })
  .ToList();
```

You can use this code as well

```
List<target> targetList = new List<target>(originalList.Cast<target>());
```

Hop this answered your question