# Java - Casting List<Object> to List<Entity>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to cast a list of Objects to a list of my own class type. So far what I'm doing is:

```
List<Company> companies = (List<Company>)(Object) repository.findAllCompanyNames();
```

`repository.findAllCompanyNames()` is returning a `List<Object>`

My Company class looks like:

```
public class Company {

    public Company(){}

    public Company(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int id;
    public String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I don't get any error the problem is the value of `companies` after the cast, it is:

```
companies = {ArrayList@11743}  size = 4
 0 = {Object[2]@11753} 
  0 = {Integer@11761} "1"
  1 = "Company 1"
 1 = {Object[2]@11754} 
  0 = {Integer@11785} "3"
  1 = "Company 3"
 2 = {Object[2]@11755} 
  0 = {Integer@11779} "4"
  1 = "Company TT"
 3 = {Object[2]@11756} 
  0 = {Integer@11764} "5"
  1 = "Company 34"
 4 = {Object[2]@11757}
```

and I think the `companies` list should contain Company objects like:

```
- Id: 1
- Name: Company 1
- etc ..
```

Any idea what it's going on?

Comment: but, from what is shown there, it does contain it? you´re just printing the additional hashcode from the class itself and the one from the `List`.

Comment: Just casting doesn't change the object at all...

Comment: What is your `repository.findAllCompanyNames` actually returning? If it isn't returning a Company casting doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @JonSkeet what is the right way to change the object? I thought casting the list would change as well the object :S

Comment: @M.Deinum ``repository.findAllCompanyNames`` return a ``List<Object>``

Comment: So what type of Object is returned there? Just `List<Object>` is pretty useless...

Comment: If casting would change the object, then every problem could be solved with this magic line `mySolutions = (List<Solutions>)(Object) myProblems; // if only`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cast List<Object> to List<MyClass>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917844/how-to-cast-listobject-to-listmyclass)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the list shouldn't contain `Company` objects because you're not retrieving companies, but their names. The method is called `findAllCompanyNames()` and it returns a `List<Object[]>` (runtime type), with each element containing (presumably) the company id and the company name.

If you show the repository class, it should be more obvious and you'll probably find a method that returns the company objects you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use `java-8`? You can just transform  a `List<Object[]>` into a `List<Company>` using `stream`:

```
List<Object[]> companies = Arrays.asList(
            new Object[]{1, "Company nam 1"}, 
            new Object[]{2, "Company nam 2"}
);
```

now we can convert `companies` to a  `List<Company>`:

```
List<Company> companyList = companies.stream().map(
               o -> new Company((Integer) o[0], (String) o[1])
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I hope this helps.