# Can't cast ArrayList class to ArrayList of interface

Tags: java, android, arraylist, casting

Code structure

```
public interface ListItem
public abstract class Device implements ListItem
public class DeviceList extends ArrayList<Device>
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
...
    public ArrayList<ListItem> items;
...
    }
```

I want to pass DeviceList to ListAdapter, but can't cast DeviceList to ArrayList< ListItem>. Why is that?

If Device implements ListItem, and DeviceList is an array list of Device, shouldn't I be able to cast it?

I try it like this:

```
ArrayList<ListItem> list2 = (ArrayList<ListItem>) device_list;
```

Comment: devicelist is of type Device and arraylist is of type listitem

Comment: Yes, but Device implements ListItem, so I should be able to cast it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a common misunderstanding. Although Device is a ListItem, a List of Devices is not a List of ListItems.
Btw, this already had been answered, see for example [How to cast List<Object> to List<MyClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917844/how-to-cast-listobject-to-listmyclass) and [How do you cast a List of supertypes to a List of subtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes)

Comment: Thanks, will accept answer as soon as I can [: